# Im am having trouble with a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

The code is messy but what I am trying to achieve is creating a class with the value of "cool" by using loops.

I started by putting each of the paragraphs in each of their own variable and then I placed them in a loop where I stated that I wanted each of them to have a classname of "cool", I also stated that I wanted this value i.e "cool" to display in the HTML just so that I can ensure that it is working, but is not going through and i would like to know what I am doing and/or you have a more efficient way of going about this.

```js
var i;
var loop1 = document.getElementById("cool");
var loop2 = document.getElementById("cool1");
var loop3 = document.getElementById("cool2");
var loop4 = document.getElementById("cool3");
var loop5 = document.getElementById("cool4");

var loops = [loop1, loop2, loop3, loop4, loop5];
var loopsLng = loops.length;

for (i = 0; i > loopsLng; i++) {
  document.getElementById(loops[i]).className = "cool";
  var one = document.getElementById(loops[i]).getAttribute("class");
  document.getElementById(loops[i]).innerHTML = one;
}
```

```html
<p id="cool" style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#b35900; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
<p id="cool1" style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#b35900; 2rem; color:white;"></p>
<p id="cool2" style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#b35900; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
<p id="cool3" style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#b35900; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
<p id="cool4" style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#b35900; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
```

Comment: `loops[i]` is an element, not an ID. So `document.getElementById(loops[i])` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just use `loops[i].getAttribute("class")`

Comment: Also, try not to use `var` anymore. It was replaced by `let` for mutable variables, and `const` for immutable variable, both using "normal" block scoping rules. And as a safe practice, use `.textContent` when setting text content for an HTML element rather than `.innerHTML` (not a problem here, but being in the habit of _not_ using innerHTML means you're not accidentally injecting user generated content into your pages in the future simply because you forgot to use .textContent instead of .innerHTML).

Comment: Another typo: `i > loopsLng` should be `i < loopsLng`. Your loop isn't even running because the condition fails immediately.

Comment: Consider using a different `for` construct.  There's lots of ways to achieve the loop and there's nothing wrong with yours, just advising of others.   eg:  `let arr = ['a','b','c'];  for (let a of arr) console.log(a)`

Comment: @Barmar thx for this. To fix this, instead of calling the element, i just placed the name of the id directly. ```var loop1 = "cool";
var loop2 = "cool1";
var loop3 = "cool2";
var loop4 = "cool3";
var loop5 = "cool4";```

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the loop itself

```
for (i = 0; i > loopsLng; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < loopsLng; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to declare the `i` variable in advance. In fact it's better if you don't, so that you don't accidentally use it outside the loop.
2. The elements don't have to be in their own variables, you can declare them all already inside the list.
3. There's no need to save the `loops.length` into its own variable either.
4. **Your `i > loopsLng` is inverted, it should be `i < loopsLng`.** This is the main problem.
5. It's nicer to store `loops[i]` in a local variable so you don't repeat it multiple times.
6. There's a better loop type you can use here, `for (const item of list)`. With this you don't have to use indexes anymore.
7. Prefer `const` and `let` instead of `var`, it'll save you some headache with variable scoping in the future.
8. `loops` is not a very descriptive name for a list of elements. Try `elements` instead.

---

```
const elements = [
    document.getElementById("cool"),
    document.getElementById("cool1"),
    document.getElementById("cool2"),
    document.getElementById("cool3"),
    document.getElementById("cool4"),
]
for (const element of elements) {
    element.className = "cool";
    element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute("class");
}
```